# Error "different prefix:" with Active_Admin gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

to install active_admin - I updated my gems, did

```
rails generate active_admin:install
rake db:migrate
```

and then I want to go localhost:3000/admin

and I get this error page

```
ArgumentError in Active_admin/devise/sessions#new

Showing D:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.3.2/app/views/layouts/active_admin_logged_out.html.erb where line #9 raised:

different prefix: "D:/" and "C:/project/app/assets/stylesheets"
  (in C:/project/app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin.css.scss)
Extracted source (around line #9):

6:   <title><%= [@page_title, active_admin_application.site_title].compact.join(" | ") %></title>
7: 
8:   <% ActiveAdmin.application.stylesheets.each do |path| %>
9:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag path %>
10:   <% end %>
11:   <% ActiveAdmin.application.javascripts.each do |path| %>
12:     <%= javascript_include_tag path %>
Rails.root: C:/project

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
Request

Parameters:

None
Show session dump

Show env dump

Response

Headers:

None
```

Note that the project folder and ruby folder are indeed in different drives (never thought it matters)

***Update***:

I have found this http://github.com/rails/rails/issues/660 which seems to be the same error with a solution, yet I don't understand what needs to be done for the error to go away.

Please help :)

Comment: It seems rails and ruby like to be on the same drive..

move the app to the same drive as ruby and it was resolved..

kinda annoying but it worked..

Comment: mklink works https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/660 it seems happening on windows

Comment: For Vista (and Windows 7 as said by @pnairn) you can do this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10540468/715424

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**I use Window XP sp3 to work with Rails**

- The path of my Ruby Installer is **C:\Ruby193**
- The path of my project is **D:\rails_projects\myApp**

**The solution:**

*Get "Junction.exe", in Windows Vista used to "mklink"*

- Download [junction.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx)
- Copy Junction.exe to **C:\Windows\System32\**

*Create simbolic link*

- Write into your console "C:\> **junction C:\myApp D:\rails_projects\myApp**
  "

*Run the myApp*

- C:\> **cd myApp**
- C:\myApp> **rails server**
- Go to http://localhost:3000/admin

It's Ok..!!!!

Comment: If you're on Windows 7, you can use the mklink command without having to install anything. See http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/

Comment: But there is need for creating links?
This seems to be a bug in Rails.

Answer (score 14):

The easiest way (for me at least) to work around this issue is to bundle your project gems into the project folder itself. From inside your project folder:

bundle install --path .bundle

This installs your project's requested gems into the .bundle folder inside the project. Subsequent calls to bundle exec will remember to use this cache of gems and should mitigate against the error above.

Answer (score 2):

Just move */assets/stylesheets/** to your project */lib/assets/stylesheets*.

No need to rename any file or dependency as this path comes before any gem path.

You can check your assets paths stack by launching a rails console : `rails c` and executing the following : `y Rails.application.config.assets.paths`.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to work it around:

1) Copy the folder with stylesheets from active admin gem folder to your app's assetes, i have it here:
c:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.2\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\activeadmin-0.3.2\app\assets\stylesheets\active_admin\

2) Rename this folder in assets for example to "my_active_admin" (you can't leave it "active_admin" - this won't work)

3) Replace "active_admin\" with "my_active_admin\" in paths to css.sss **in two files in this folder: _base.css.scss and _mixings.css.scss** and also in **active_admin.css.scss**

And dot forget to remove/fix **require tree** in application.css if you use it.

Voila! Update the admin page without fear =)

Though I don't like such solutions much in terms of need for excessive hacks... 
BUT now you can freely customize look and feel of the active admin, and it turns to be not the hack for the bug, but for the feature =)